# Paymill Transaction Failure (code 50000) starting with 10.04.2018

Tags: transactions, error-code, paymill

Has anyone else had issues with Paymill transactions recently failing with **code 50000** (starting with 10.04.2018) and have a fix for this?

---

*The context, after several calls with their support team:*

- They changed the banking provider they collaborate with and had some data migration issues which aren't solved to this day.
- Our particular issue is that our clients' existing payment methods aren't working. They were probably not ported to their new banking system.
- The only --let's say-- **solution** we've found is to kindly ask our clients to **re-register their credit cards**.
- I hoping we're not a single, isolated unlucky case so maybe someone else can share their experience on this.

Comment: For future reference I have had huge problems with Paymill. They still owe me a lot of money and all transactions on non-amex cards fail. I don't recommend anyone to use them.

Comment: Oh yes, I can fully confirm this. On July 2019 we've had another huge problem with them. The bank backing them (based on Luxembourg) was blocked by the CSSF and they did not release any funds anymore because apparently they couldn't, from a legal stand. And that's fine, so to speak, accidents happen, BUT their attitude was beyond terrible. Total silence, no answer on phone or email, zero reaction. A FB community on this subject was actually created after this event to which I was invited, and there are a lot of people who where practically scammed by Paymill. For some, adding up to 100K EUR.

Comment: Needless to say, since July 2019 we moved away from them and went on with another payment processor.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. On July all transactions started failing and they stopped payouts for everything else than amex (since that is controlled by another bank). Slow response times on support and the issues you mentioned was my experience too. I also switched to another payment provider. Did you ever get what they owed you? I'm still waiting. I even tried to cancel my account with them in hope of that would release the money. It doesn't.

Comment: No, not to this day. Luckily, in our case, we aren't talking about a huge amount, it's less than 1K EUR.

Comment: Still sucks. Thank you for the feedback.